# Setting asynctimeout property for scriptmanager in web part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have a web part which takes long time to load and results in time out. I read there is a property in scriptmanager which by default is set to 90 seconds.

Is there some way to increase this timeout for this webpart without modifying scriptmanager code in master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Just write the following in your web part and you are done.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;
```

Where 600 is number of seconds.